# What is an effective way to get the count of file types on the drive?

Tags: windows-7, media, file-types

I have a 2TB drive with a ton of media from the last 10 years.  Audio, video, photos, etc...  Ton of files.

Is there an effective way to summarize the file types on the drive?  For instance, I'd like to see how many music files (.wav, .mp3, .aac, etc...), videos (.mp4, m4v, .mpg, .avi, .mkv, etc...), photos (.png, .jpg), etc... I have.

Comment: If they are media files, you can use any media-manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method would be to use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). For example, you can search for `*.AVI` and Everything will give you the number of AVI files in the drive in a few seconds.

Another method would be to use scripts. [This](http://vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=247) is an example of VBA code, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320731/count-number-of-files-with-certain-extension-in-python) is an example of Python code.

You may also use a command line script to count files by a particular file type. Example:

```
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/s/b/a-d "C:\*.avi"') do (
set /a count+=1
)

echo %count%
```

Answer (score 4):

I think WinDirStat might also have this functionality and it's an awesome way to view windows disk usage.   It color codes the various file types.

http://windirstat.info/

Answer (score 1):

I edit Mehper's answer for use in a command prompt: delete one % in %%a and put it in one line:

```
set /a count=0 & for /f "tokens=* delims= " %a in ('dir/s/b/a-d "*.avi"') do (set /a count+=1)
```

Comment: This may be the correct way to type the command interactively into a Command Prompt, but Mehper's answer says, "You may also use a command line script ...", and `%%a` is the correct syntax for use in a script.

Comment: Mmh, I see, thanks, I edited the wording of my sentence.